# How do I fix Grails 6 integration tests failing due to i18n messages not being found?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am having issues with resolving i18n messages in my integration tests after upgrading our Grails application to 6.0.0 from 5.3.2. I'm getting a similar error for 26 out of our 110 integration tests:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'itemDisplayDateTimeFormat' for locale 'en'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:161)
    at com.hypercision.attproto.device.DeviceManagementController.getDataForDeviceApproval(DeviceManagementController.groovy:93)
    at com.hypercision.attproto.device.DeviceManagementController.getDataForDeviceApproval(DeviceManagementController.groovy)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$MethodHandleInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:223)
```

This is happening on my local machine and in our CircleCI workflow. I tried deleting the `.gradle` directory at the project root, but that did not fix the errors.

I was able to get one of our service integration tests passing again by manually creating and injecting a `StaticMessageSource` like we have already been doing in our unit tests:

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class SubmissionServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    SubmissionService submissionService

    StaticMessageSource staticMessageSource = new StaticMessageSource()

    def setup() {
        staticMessageSource.addMessage("SubmissionService.submit.sessionAlreadySubmittedError",
                Locale.US, "session already submitted")
        submissionService.setMessageSource(staticMessageSource)
    }

    def setupData() {
        // omitting some domain classes that are created here
    }
    
    def "test submitAllSessionsInGroup when the SessionItem is in a group of two and there are errors"() {
        given: "the SessionItem is in a SessionItemGroup that has 2 sessionItems"
        setupData()
        assert sessionItemGroup.getSize() == 2
        and: "One of the sessionItems is submitted"
        sessionItem1.status = "Submitted"
        assert sessionItem2.status == "Not Started"
        assert sessionItem2.submitTS == null

        when:
        submissionService.submitAllSessionsInGroup(sessionItem1)

        then:
        InvalidSessionItemStatusException exception = thrown()
        exception != null
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how we'd do that with our controller integration tests, like the one below:

```
// src/integration-test/groovy/com/hypercision/attproto/device/DeviceManagementControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy
package com.hypercision.attproto.device

import com.hypercision.attproto.instructor.Instructor
import com.hypercision.attproto.serviceaccount.ServiceAccount
import grails.gorm.transactions.Rollback
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException
import io.micronaut.http.uri.UriBuilder
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@Integration
@Rollback
class DeviceManagementControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared HttpClient client
    @Shared String accessToken
    @Shared Instructor instructor
    @Shared List<Device> devices = []

    void setup() {
        // Use the ServiceAccount created in Bootstrap.groovy
        ServiceAccount serviceAccount = ServiceAccount.first()
        assert serviceAccount
        instructor = new Instructor(userID: UUID.randomUUID().toString(), fullName: "Wendy",
                serviceAccount: serviceAccount).save(failOnError: true)
        Device device1 = new Device(deviceID: UUID.randomUUID().toString(), registrationCode: "111",
                platform: "iOS", platformVersion: "12.1.0", instructor: instructor).save(failOnError: true)
        Device device2 = new Device(deviceID: UUID.randomUUID().toString(), registrationCode: "222",
                platform: "Android", platformVersion: "9.0.0", instructor: instructor,
                approvalToken: "aaabbb123").save(failOnError: true)
        devices = [device1, device2]
    }

    void cleanup() {
        Device.deleteAll(Device.getAll())
        instructor.delete()
    }

    @Unroll
    void "test getDataForDeviceApproval returns 200"() {
        given:
        assert Device.count == 2
        final String uriPath = '/deviceManagement/getDataForDeviceApproval'
        String uri = UriBuilder.of(uriPath)
                .queryParam("token", devices[1].approvalToken)
                .queryParam("lang", lang)
                .build()

        when: "we call the method being tested"
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.GET(uri)
        HttpResponse<String> resp = this.client.toBlocking().exchange(request, String)
        Map json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(resp.body()) as Map

        then: "we get a success status"
        resp.status == HttpStatus.OK
        json != null
        json.id == devices[1].id
        json.deviceID == devices[1].deviceID
        json.platform == devices[1].platform
        json.approved == devices[1].approved

        and: "the response has the correct dateformat for the locale of the request"
        json.itemDisplayDateTimeFormat == format

        when: "we call the method again with a bad approval token"
        uri = UriBuilder.of(uriPath)
                .queryParam("token", "this_does_not_match_any_saved_devices")
                .queryParam("lang", lang)
                .build()

        request = HttpRequest.GET(uri)
        this.client.toBlocking().exchange(request, String)

        then: "we get a 400 status"
        HttpClientResponseException ex = thrown()
        HttpResponse<String> exResponse = ex.response as HttpResponse<String>
        Map exJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(exResponse.body()) as Map
        exResponse.status == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST

        and:
        exJson != null
        exJson.errors != null
        exJson.errors.size() == 1
        exJson.errors[0].message == "Invalid token: device not found with that token."

        where:
        lang | format
        "en" | "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm z"
        "en_GB" | "d MMM yyyy HH:mm z"
    }
}
```

Update: I created a sample Grails 6.0.0 project and have not yet been able to reproduce the issue, so it very likely something is wrong with our application's configuration which is causing the NoSuchMessageExceptions.

Comment: I am running into same exact issue, and I can see that when it loads the resources in test context it is loading the resources file from a grails plugin that I use as a dependency. Found it out by putting debug point in ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource class, loadResources method. Not sure why it does that though! Then I also noticed that it tries to load to resource in "locateResourceWithoutCache" method, which was by default trying to load messages_en properties file. So i just renamed my messages.properties to messages_en.properties and now the tests are passing.

Answer (score 1):

In my application where the issue is happening, I noticed that the controller integration test cases with a non-English locale passed. I am specifying the locale by setting the `lang` param in the URL when calling my controller method i.e. `lang=es`.

When I added a `messages_en.properties` file with the same contents as my `messages.properties` file, then all my integration tests passed. So for now, my workaround is creating a symbolic link to messages.properties and committing that file to our repository:

```bash
cd grails-app/i18n
ln -s messages.properties messages_en.properties
```